# PHP/HTML Basic File Writing Using a Form

Tags: php, html, forms, file

I am just beginning to play around with PHP and HTML and need help with writing form input to a text file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        Create Address Book Record
        </br></br>
        <form id="CreateAddress" action="CreateAddr.php" method="post">
            User ID: <input type="text" name="User ID" /></br></br>
            Name: <input type="text" name="Name" /></br></br>
            Phone No.: <input type="text" name="Phone No." /></br></br>
            Address: <input type="text" name="Address" /></br></br>
            <input name="Create" type="submit" value="Create"/></br></br>
        </form>
        <a href='addrbook.txt'>Address Book</a></br>
    </body>
</html>
```

CreateAddr.php:

```
<?php
    include 'CreateAddrForm.html';

    $file = fopen("addrbook.txt", "a+");
    $status = false;
    $data = '';

    if (isset($_POST['User ID']) && isset($_POST['Name'])
        && isset($_POST['Phone No.']) && isset($_POST['Address']))
    {
        echo "hi";
        $data = $_POST['User ID'] . "\n" . $_POST['Name'] . 
            "\n" . $_POST['Phone No.'] . "\n" . $_POST['Address'] . "\n";
        echo $data;
        $status = fwrite($file, $data);
        if($status === false)
            die('There was an error writing this file');
        else
            echo $status . "bytes written to file";
    }
    else 
        die('no post data to process');
?>
```

The outer if statement is never entered, the output is always "no data to process." Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: your field names have probably been mangled by PHP. do a `var_dump($_POST)` to see what happened. field names should generally not have spaces or punctuation in them. try using `UserID` and `PhoneNo` instead.

Comment: @MarcB that was indeed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I knew that ;-) I wanted PHP to tell you itself.

Comment: I know beginners don't like to hear this, but its better to use a db because multiple users writing to one file will result in access sharing violations.

Comment: @developerwjk A DB is indeed better, however file locking would be beneficial.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I didn't see anything come up. Where would that info have appeared?

Comment: @developerwjk, I'm working on it ;)

Comment: It would have/should have appeared on your screen. Something to the effect of `Notice: Undefined index: Phone No. in...` having used `<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Please choose the name very carefully here in your code your Phone No. is the problem because the key of Phone No. in  `$_Post` array is `Phone_No_`

Avoid white spaces in your name it makes it a lot easier. I recommend to use [Camel Case](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) instead.

**HTML :**

```
**<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        Create Address Book Record
        </br></br>
        <form id="CreateAddress" action="CreateAddr.php" method="post">
            User ID: <input type="text" name="User ID" /></br></br>
            Name: <input type="text" name="Name" /></br></br>
            Phone No.: <input type="text" name="Phone No." /></br></br>
            Address: <input type="text" name="Address" /></br></br>
            <input name="Create" type="submit" value="Create"/></br></br>
        </form>
        <a href='addrbook.txt'>Address Book</a></br>
    </body>
</html>**
```

**PHP :**

```
<?php
    include 'CreateAddrForm.html';

    $file = fopen("addrbook.txt", "a+");
    $status = false;
    $data = '';

    if (isset($_POST['User_ID']) && isset($_POST['Name'])&& isset($_POST['Phone_No_']) && isset($_POST['Address'])) {

        echo "hi";
        $data = $_POST['User_ID'] . "\n" . $_POST['Name'] . 
            "\n" . $_POST['Phone_No'] . "\n" . $_POST['Address'] . "\n";
        echo $data;
        $status = fwrite($file, $data);
        if($status === false)
            die('There was an error writing this file');
        else
            echo $status . "bytes written to file";
    }
    else 
        die('no post data to process');
?>
```